# spaCy similarity - Setting sense2vec or word2vec as default

Tags: nlp, word2vec, spacy, sense2vec

I came across one of spaCy's blog's [post](https://explosion.ai/blog/sense2vec-with-spacy) which introduces the sense2vec idea and there's also an online interface to play with it's [most similar function](https://demos.explosion.ai/sense2vec/?word=natural%20language%20processing&sense=auto) while there's also an [online tool](https://demos.explosion.ai/similarity) to play with the similarity function, brought by spaCy.

I just couldn't understand if those tools are based on the sense2vec algorithm or just normal pre-trained word2vec model (I'm talking about the large English model).

Is there a way to define with which model to I would like to work with?

The point is that

Answer (score 0):

You can load your own vectors by following [these instructions in the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity#custom-loading-other). Using that process, you should be able to load in the sense2vec vectors.

The models that are used for the `.similarity()` methods are either the full word2vec model or tensors, depending on whether you're using the large or small model. The [sentence similarity tool](https://demos.explosion.ai/similarity) you linked to describes this:

> By default, spaCy uses an average-of-vectors algorithm, using pre-trained vectors if available (e.g. the en_core_web_lg model). If not, the doc.tensor attribute is used, which is produced by the tagger, parser and entity recognizer. This is how the en_core_web_sm model provides similarities. Usually the .tensor-based similarities will be more structural, while the word vector similarities will be more topical. You can also customize the .similarity() method, to provide your own similarity function, which can be trained using supervised techniques.

Comment: I know how to read their documentary and did it before asking. You didn't answer my question, my question is - If now I load a vector for a given sentence, will this vector be loaded from a simple word2vec/glove model or from a sense2vec model? In order to use sense2vec am I suppose to manually add POS tag to each token and just than transform using the model or transform as is and it'll give the proper sense2vec vector?

Comment: The vector for a sentence, by default, will be an average of the default Glove vectors of the words in that sentence.

Each token already has a POS ascribed to it when it is parsed, so you won't have to do that. You can use this fact and `vocab.set_vector()` to use the sense2vec vectors. (see here: https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity#custom-vectors-add)

Comment: I saw this link and still don't understand how do I get to a sense2vec vectors. I don't want to train new vectors but want each vector to be based both on context (word2vec/Glove) but also will have the POS tags/NER tags included so it'll differentiate, for example, between Apple (the fruit) and Apple (the company), how do I get such vectors? or is it just available as an online demo?

Comment: My understanding is that you'd have to go through the vocabulary you're using and assign the vectors from sense2vec to each token manually. I'm not sure of the best way to do that, but it's theoretically possible. There is no easy solution that just tells spacy to use sense2vec instead of GloVe.